# growth scale for entire functions?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I came across this while reading Ya. Levin's book. Let $f$ be an entire function and $r>0$. Define $$M_f(r)=\mbox{max}_{|z|=r}|f(z)|\;.$$
One can express $f$ in power series as
$$
f(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n~,~~\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=0\;.
$$
He asks the question whether $M_f(r)$ can grow arbitrarily fast. This is a nice question, but where would you begin to try to investigate this?

Answer (score 0):

Take any sequence $z_n$ with $|z_n| = n$, and any sequence of positive numbers $v_n$.  Find a sequence of polynomials 
$p_n(z)$ such that $p_n(z_n) = v_n$, $p_n(z_j) = 0$ for $j < n$, and $|p_n(z)| \le 2^{-n}$ on $\{z: |z| < n-1\}$.  Then $f(z) = \sum_n p_n(z)$ is entire and has 
$M_f(n) \ge v_n$.